# Reading characters "ěščřž..." from Word doc file via php function, returns question mark in diamond

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, doc

i found function in PHP, that reads MS Word **.doc** files quite good, but when file contains some of "ěščř..." character, it returns question mark in diamont character (unrecognized character?)

function looks like this

```
if ( file_exists($filename) ) {

        if ( ($fh = fopen($filename, 'r')) !== false ) {

            $headers = fread($fh, 0xA00);

            # 1 = (ord(n)*1) ; Document has from 0 to 255 characters
            $n1 = ( ord($headers[0x21C]) - 1 );

            # 1 = ((ord(n)-8)*256) ; Document has from 256 to 63743 characters
            $n2 = ( ( ord($headers[0x21D]) - 8 ) * 256 );

            # 1 = ((ord(n)*256)*256) ; Document has from 63744 to 16775423 characters
            $n3 = ( ( ord($headers[0x21E]) * 256 ) * 256 );

            # (((ord(n)*256)*256)*256) ; Document has from 16775424 to 4294965504 characters
            $n4 = ( ( ( ord($headers[0x21F]) * 256 ) * 256 ) * 256 );

            # Total length of text in the document
            $textLength = ($n1 + $n2 + $n3 + $n4);

            $extracted_plaintext = fread($fh, $textLength);

            # if you want the plain text with no formatting, do this
            //echo $extracted_plaintext;
            echo mb_detect_encoding($extracted_plaintext);

            # if you want to see your paragraphs in a web page, do this
            echo nl2br($extracted_plaintext);

        }

    }
```

Also im trying to change character encoding to UTF-8 in which i have whole web content by something like this

```
$extracted_plaintext = iconv("UTF-8","UTF-8//IGNORE",$extracted_plaintext);
```

But it only removes invalid characters, so text is also unreadable. So im not sure, if this issue is realy in charset, or anything else? I think UTF-8 is correct, because if i use
 `echo mb_detect_encoding($extracted_plaintext);` it returns UTF-8

edit: [here](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18032222/myDoc.doc) is attached example of file

Comment: Yes right,Its UTF-8 character encoding issue

Comment: @manoj.kadlag and do you know, how to solve it? or atleast where issue can be? File is saved as UTF-8, i transforming everything to UTF-8 and even script returns information, that string is in UTF-8?

Comment: can u share the word file?

Comment: @manoj.kadlag sorry for delay, .doc file is avaliable here https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18032222/myDoc.doc

Comment: In fact, `mb_detect_encoding()` does not really do what everybody assumes by its name. In any case, legacy Microsoft Word format is rather old and comes from Windows world. Are you positively sure it's using UTF-8 and not UTF-16 or some ANSI encoding?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález can i somehow figure out which encoding is it using? i tried multiple html header, but without success

Comment: You can either guess from the [hexadecimal representation](http://php.net/bin2hex) or find documentation about the format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read doc/ppt file is kinda problematic (and not even talking about special character) So i found more usable to convert document into pdf and then read pdf which is much more easier. Maybe this will help someone in future to not waste as much time as i to try to read .doc or .ppt

Answer (score 0):

Have you try another code page?

In my experience, document of Microsoft Office always using localized encoding , say Big5 when Taiwan region.

"Question mark in diamont character" always means wrong encoding but trying to read by UTF8. Try to view my **BIG5** forum in **UTF8** http://www.gundamhk.com/

edit:
I have figured out that is not UTF-8 of your doc but the nearest charsets are:

- Windows-1250,
- Windows-1252
- ISO-8859-1
- ISO-8859-2

(And the other similar name)
To view the nearest result, use this:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=Windows-1250');
```

I cannot find the exact match code page of these character, but just have a look on [PHP official supported character set](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.supported-encodings.php)
, these character seems not in that list.It may very pain if you still have to handle these characters.

Comment: Not sure if understands you well, but i tried multiple documents, and this one is manualy created for testing, on same enviroment as script runs.

Comment: yes also this file. Its just minimalised example of what i have in other files

Comment: Another question, have you set the http header charset as UTF8?

Comment: Yes, i think this `echo "<meta charset='UTF-8'>";` is enough.

Comment: I mean this: header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

Comment: Please try Windows-1250, got a similar result.

Comment: I tried and still no result, so i think to stop trying this way and think about other else solution. Like export ppt to pdf and then read pdf which is not so problematic. But thanks for your effort